# Shiny image hosting

Tags: r, image, shiny, hosting

I have been trying to make a **very** simple app using shiny that basically does this:

1. Let's users upload a photo
2. Downloads a csv file with the public links to each photo (this is to be used by shopify to download the images and re-upload to their servers)

I am having trouble doing the second part.

Both Dropbox and Google Drive let me store objects using their API and r packages, but they have deprecated a url to the direct object, instead opting for a "preview" version of the file, which of course makes shopify go crazy and reject my url.

Any thoughts as what other storage service or workaround that can work?

Comment: have you considered using AWS's S3?